# PyCharm install package with square brackets

Tags: python, pycharm, stable-baselines

I want to install "stabe-baselines3[extra]"
But in the PyCharm Package installer is only "stable-baselines3" available.

[image]

When try to install it via 'pip install' I do get this error:

[image]
Translation: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

How do I get the [extra]?

Comment: Hope that answer helps. Please remember to drop me a comment if I did not answer your question so that I can continue to try to help you get this resolved :)

Comment: The titular question isn't representative of the presented problem.

Answer (score 3):

From: https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3

[image: installing stable baselines 3 vs 3 extra]

So are you actually needing that additional functionality for atari games?

If so, then you can just use the built-in `Terminal` to manually install the package you are needing:

[image]

Which if you didn't already know, can be found right here:

[image]

Otherwise, you can just use stable-baselines3, as you have already found is available within the package manager.

Comment: I get this error when i try 'pip install'

Comment: @MalteSchulzeBalhorn try `python -m pip install SomePackage`

Answer (score 0):

The terminal has to be used. Reason the terminal hasn't worked is because in the settings 'Start directory' hasn't been the Python Scripts folder but the main-file folder.
After that folder change the pip install command worked!